# fwprintf is printing out garbage

Tags: c++, winapi, printf

I have a program that gets the list of a directory ( selected by the user ) and writes the list of directories and files associated in that directory. However when printing to the file, it always prints out a '?' then a random character after that. I'm working on winapi, visual c++ 2010 express. I'm using unicode as well ( so i'm using wide characters ). I'm guessing my problem is in the fwprintf function that I'm using because it adds the directories/files to my std::list that i have correctly. This is my current function:

```
// global list for testing
std::list<std::wstring> lDirectories;

void CleanupContents( const wchar_t *sDir )
{
  ListDirectoryContents( sDir ) // function that adds each file and directory to the std::list

  wchar_t dir[ MAX_PATH * 10 ];
  wsprintf( dir, L"%s\\ListOfFilesAndDirectories.txt", sDir );

  FILE* pFile;
  errno_t err = _wfopen_s( &pFile, dir, L"w" );

  while( !lDirectories.empty() )
  {
    fwprintf( pFile, L"%s", lDirectories.front() );
    lDirectories.pop_front();
  }

  err = fclose( pFile );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
fwprintf( pFile, L"%s", lDirectories.front() );
```

`fwprintf` expects a `wchar_t*` and you provide a `wstring`.

Change to:

```
fwprintf( pFile, L"%s", lDirectories.front().c_str() );
```

Comment: Ugh. I have those simple errors. I've been stuck for hours on that. >.< Programming...drives me crazy sometimes ;)